# Controller Not A Function When Placing HTML into ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I've split my HTML off into a view using angular, but when I've done so I get the error:

> Argument 'EventController' is not a function

This worked previously with no issue, it's only since I've tried splitting them off and writing a route and I'm really struggling to see what the problem is? I've checked all the spelling of the files, script declarations etc and that all seems fine.

My base index page is:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Create Event</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#/events">Events List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/newEvent">Create Event</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ng-view></ng-view>

        </div>

        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/EditEventController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/EventList.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services/EventData.js"></script>
        <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML I'm putting in the view is:

```
<div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
    <img ng-src="{{event.imageUrl}}" alt="{{event.name}}" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="scrollToSession()">Scroll to Session</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="spann1">
            <!--Style and Bind Template Directives w/ Uppercase Filter-->
            <h2 ng-style="mystyle" ng-bind-template="{{event.name | uppercase}}"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Disabled Directive-->
    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="buttonDisabled">Disabled</button>

    <!--Non-Bindable Directive-->
    <div ng-non-bindable="nonBindable">{{1 + 2}}</div>

    <!--Hide/Show & Class Directive-->
    <h2 ng-show="boolValue">Show This</h2>
    <h2 ng-hide="boolValue" ng-class="myclass">Hide This</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <!--Date Filter-->
            <div><strong>Date:</strong> {{event.date | date:'mediumDate'}}</div>
            <div><strong>Time:</strong> {{event.time}}</div>
            <!--Currency Filter-->
            <div><strong>Price:</strong> {{event.price | currency:'£'}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <address>
                <strong>Address:</strong><br />
                {{event.location.address}}<br />
                {{event.location.city}}, {{event.location.province}}
            </address>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!--Expressions-->
    {{[1,2,3][2]}}

    <!--Number Filter-->
    <div>{{3 | number:2}}</div>

    <!--JSON Filter-->
    <div>{{ { a:3, b:'hi', c:{aa:35} } | json }}</div>

    <!--Repeat Directive-->
    <hr />
    <h3>Sessions</h3>
    <div>
        Order By:
        <select ng-model="sortOrder" class="input-small">
            <option value="name">Name Asc</option>
            <option value="-name">Name Desc</option>
            <option value="creatorName">Creator Asc</option>
            <option value="-creatorName">Creator Desc</option>
            <option value="level">Level Asc</option>
            <option value="-level">Level Desc</option>
        </select>

        Show:
        <select ng-model="difficulty.level" class="input-small">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
            <option value="Introductory">Introductory</option>
            <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions | orderBy:sortOrder | limitTo:3 | filter:difficulty" id={{session.id}}>
            <div class="row session">
                <div class="span0 well votingWidget">
                    <div ng-click="upVoteSession(session)" class="votingButton">
                        <i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="badge badge-inverse">
                        <div>{{session.upVoteCount}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-click="downVoteSession(session)" class="votingButton">
                        <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="well span9">
                    <h4 class="well-title">{{session.name}}</h4>
                    <h6 style="margin-top:-10px;">{{session.creatorName}}</h6>
                    <!--Custom Filter-->
                    <span>Duration: {{session.duration | durations}}</span><br />
                    <span>Level: {{session.level}}</span>

                    <p>{{session.abstract}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The route data is:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/newEvent', {
            templateUrl:'templates/NewEvent.html',
            controller: 'EditEventController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/events', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/EventList.html',
            controller: 'EventListController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/events/:eventId', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/EventDetails.html',
            controller: 'EventController'
        });
    }
);
```

And the EventController.js file:

```
'use strict';

eventsApp.controller('EventController', function($scope, eventData, $anchorScroll){

    $scope.snippet = '<span style="color:red;">hi there</span>';

    $scope.boolValue = false;

    $scope.mystyle = {color:'red'};

    $scope.myclass = "blue";

    $scope.buttonDisabled = false;

    $scope.nonBindable = true;

    $scope.sortOrder = 'name';

    $scope.difficulty = "";

    eventData.getEvent()
        .$promise.then(
            function(event) {$scope.event = event; console.log(event);}
        ).catch(function(response) {console.log(response);}
    );

    $scope.upVoteSession = function(session){
        session.upVoteCount++;
    }

    $scope.downVoteSession = function(session){
        session.upVoteCount--;
    }

    $scope.scrollToSession() = function() {
        $anchorScroll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Was that controller ever declared differently like `eventsApp.controller('EventController', EventController)` ... `function EventController($scope, eventData, $anchorScroll` ?)

Comment: It's always been Event Controller - I've never changed it

Comment: ok...so never passed in named function?  The `argument` part of error made me wonder

Comment: Nope always just been that way I've not touched it

Comment: So what splitting are you actually referring to? Creating multiple files from one? And you are sure file is loading in dev tools network?

Comment: I mean using routing to place the contents of EventDetails.html inside index.html using ng-view

Comment: If you comment out that route do other controllers in routing work properly?

Comment: Yeah no problems with the others

Comment: Hard to help more without being able to inspect in browser. Any chance you left an `ng-controller` in when switching?

Comment: Did a find on ng-controller, but nothing

Comment: might try removing `Use strict` temporarily also

Comment: Getting rid of 'use strict' worked - from the network stats I think what might have been happening is that app.j was loading in ever so slightly after the controller but by taking off use strict it's put the loading times right

Comment: well actually because you aren't wrapping it in an IIFE it makes `use strict` global and something somewhere isn't quite right

Comment: When I took use strict off, it did tell me there was a problem insde the controller with the scrollToSession function, so I've just taken it out - at this point I'm only learning when directives do and how the route and what not so at the moment as long as I know that didn't work because something was wrong inside the controller, then that's fine :)

Comment: Might want to go through [John Papa angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) and fine tune based on it

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. At least you found issue. Was going to suggest looking for syntax problems but I didn't see any , now I see it...extra `()`. Your IDE should have found that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that "use strict" is causing function declaration to break due to syntax error and not throwing specific syntax error in console:

Remove extra `()`

```
$scope.scrollToSession() = function() {
                   // ^^ shouldn't be here
        $anchorScroll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess since you don't have a reference to your module when defining a controller it won't define it as it should. So try changing your first line from:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController', ...
```

to:

```
angular.module('eventsApp').controller('EventController', ...
```

Note that `eventsApp` is just a local variable in your main file.

Comment: this is a better practice in general also

Answer (score 0):

In which file do you define eventsApp? It looks like you may be attempting to use EventController before it is loaded.

[image]

Comment: It's in app.js which should load before the controller in EventController

Comment: can't really use it before it is loaded...angular doesn't bootstrap until dom is loaded and the same module already exists